# Can I trigger the browser to show autocomplete suggestions via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the html datalist to make autocomplete options for a text input. I would like to know if rather than double clicking on the input if I can trigger the suggestions to appear from javascript when a button is clicked on.

```
<datalist id='gradeSuggestions'>
    <option value='A'>A</option>
    <option value='B'>B</option>
    <option value='C'>C</option>
</datalist>

<input name="grade[]" autocomplete="off" list='gradeSuggestions' type='text' />

<input type='button' id='showSuggestions' value='Show Suggestions' />

<script>
$('#showSuggestions').on('click', function(){
   // show the suggestions below the text input 
});
</script>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WQMYQ/)

Comment: Which browser are you using? I believe you shouldn't have to double-click on the text input box or click a button. I'm looking at your jsFiddle using Chrome and the autocomplete options are showing up as I type.

Comment: I don't want to type either though. I want the user to see ALL of the suggestions before typing anything.

Comment: Why not use a select box then? The datalist support is poor anyway (safari, <IE10), which excludes a lot of users!

Comment: The user needs to be able to type in a custom value if they choose. Basically a combo box which html doesn't provide. I tried placing a select under a text input and filling the text input with the items that were selected but it has usability problems. I suppose I could go try a js library to get a combobox but I wanted to know if this way was possible first as it would be easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kmzh/)***

If you merely want to show the autocomplete feature on the first click, then you can do some focus detection to trigger it to appear. When the user depresses the mouse on the input, you can give the input focus. The click event will bubble and the input will think that the input was clicked twice causing the autocomplete to show.

```
$('#grade').mousedown(function(){
 if( document.activeElement == this )return;
 $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: It seems like my original question isn't exactly possible but this solution is interesting and I may be able to use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/6Z88x/)***

It does not seem possible to force the suggestions to show on the input as a dropdown. However, you can psuedo-recreate the functionality you are looking for using jQuery's `.on('input` API along side a div which shows the suggestions.

```
$('#grade').on('input focus', function(){
 // show the suggestions below the text input 
 var inp = $("#grade").val().toLowerCase();
 var sgst = [];
 var opts = $("#gradeSuggestions")[0].options;
 for( var opt in opts ){
   if( !opts[opt].hasOwnProperty("nodeName") )continue;
   if( opts[opt].value.toLowerCase().indexOf(inp) > -1 ) sgst.push(opts[opt].value); 
 }
 var s = $("#suggestions");
 s.html('');
 for( var sg in sgst ){
    var sug = $('<div>'+sgst[sg]+'</div>');
    (function(val){
     sug.click(function(){
        $("#grade").val(val);
        $("#grade").focus();
     });
    })(sgst[sg]);
    s.append(sug);
 }
});
```